# Download mySQL table as tab delimited file from WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a button on a WordPress form that triggers an enqueued script with the intention of creating and downloading a mySQL table extract as a tab delimited file to the user's PC. The routing works fine. I can extract the data from the table and format it. I just cannot work out how to trigger the download using the PHP Header and resource directives. Any help would be appreciated.

The code snippet is below:

```
<?php
function agp_export_csv_table()
{
// =============================================================================
// This function retrieves data from the enquiries table and exports it to a
// tab delimited Excel file
// =============================================================================
    global $wpdb, $bp;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}ppl_enquiries";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);

    $filename = "Export_excel.xls";
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename);
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));

    $file = fopen($filename, 'w');

    $blnHeaderDone = false;

    if (!empty($results)) {
        foreach ($results as $row) {
            if (!$blnHeaderDone) {
                fwrite($file, implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n");
                $blnHeaderDone = true;
            }
            fwrite($file, implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n");
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
    exit();
}

?>
```

My expectation is that this should trigger a download dialogue in the user's browser but I get nothing back and I can't see that there has been any output generated either server side or on the local PC. I'm not getting any errors in either PHP or javascript that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the headers after closing the file.

```
            fclose($fp);

            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($filename) . "\"");
            header("Content-Type: application/text");
            header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
            readfile($filename);
            header("Connection: close");

            exit;
```

Comment: thank you. I had tried both before and after the write with no success but what I was missing was the readfile directive. I have a supplemental question though. The file is now created but in the wp-admin directory of my wordpress implementation. I think this is because the PHP function that does the file creation is being triggered via an ajax call made via wp-admin. Is there a way I can change that behaviour and make the file download directly from the user's browser session?